# Как сделать чтобы DBDateTimeEditEh редактировал поле записи выделенной в DBGrid-е?

Tags: delphi, firedac

столкнулся с проблемой редактирования  даты через DBDateTimeEditEh.

Подключение к БД (SQLite) устроено так:  FDConnection -> FDQuery -> DataSource

На форме лежит DBEditEh, DBDateTimeEditEh, DBGridEh все они берут данные из DataSource.

Когда я перемещаю курсор в DBGrid-е, DBEditEh и DBDateTimeEditEh получают данные выделенной записи, соответственно имя и дату. При правке имени (DBEditEh) все происходит корректно, а вот при изменении даты (DBDateTimeEditEh) курсор перемещается на последнюю запись и дата изменяется у нее, а не у выделенной записи.

Как сделать чтобы DBDateTimeEditEh редактировал поле выделенной в DBGrid-е записи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему проблема была в том что я тупо копипастнул визуальные компоненты из другого проекта. После сборки тестового проекта с нуля все заработало.